# Como posso salvar os dados vindos do parse.com na memória do aparelho?

Tags: android, android-studio, parse

Estou tentando fazer algo simples, mas pra mim um pouco complicado, estou tentando salvar os dados vindo do *parse.com* no aparelho, pois quando tem conexão com a internet ele funciona, mas quando não tem, o aparelho não salva os dados na memória, portanto os dados só aparecem quando tem rede.

Gostaria que os dados fossem salvos e sempre que reconhecesse a internet os dados fossem sincronizados, atualizados.

Estou tentando isso:

```java
public class Pizzarias extends ActionBarActivity {
    // Declare Variables
    Boolean bColorStatus = true;
    TextView status;
    ListView listview;
    List<ParseObject> ob;

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ListViewAdapterPizzarias adapter;
    private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizzarias);

        new RemoteDataTask().execute();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_pizzarias, menu);

        //Os metodos abaixo são para mostrar o icone do aplicativo na action bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        return true;
    }


    //RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Pizzarias.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Carregando Pizzarias");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array
            worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();


            try {

                String objectId = "GFiBnjCE4v";
                ParseObject feed = ParseQuery.get(objectId);
                feed.fetch();
                feed.put("fechado", true);
                feed.saveEventually();


                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.get("GerenciarPizzariasPatos")
                        .fromLocalDatastore()
                        .whereEquals("fechado", true)
                        .findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                                // "feed" ParseObject will be returned in the list of results
                            }
                        });

                // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
                // by ascending,

                query.orderByAscending("nome");

                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                    WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
                    map.setNome((String) country.get("nome"));
                    map.setEndereco((String) country.get("endereco"));
                    map.setTelefone((String) country.get("telefone"));
                    map.setStatus((String) country.get("status"));
                    worldpopulationlist.add(map);

                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewpizzarias);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapterPizzarias(Pizzarias.this,
                    worldpopulationlist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
}
```

Essas duas linhas do código estão dando erro, aparece abaixo do `get` uma linha *ondulada vermelha* indicando o erro.

```java
ParseObject feed = ParseQuery.get(objectId);
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.get("GerenciarPizzariasPatos")
```

Erros:

> Error:(100, 46) error: non-static method get(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
>   where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends ParseObject declared in class ParseQuery
>
> Error:(106, 59) error: non-static method get(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
>   where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends ParseObject declared in class ParseQuery
>
> Error:(107, 25) error: cannot find symbol method fromLocalDatastore()

Comment: Você já tem toda a estrutura de banco de dados no seu aplicativo ou é a partir desse ponto que você precisa de ajuda?

Comment: @Paulo Rodrigues. Eu tenho os dados recebidos do Parse.com, daí gostaria que quando eu ficasse sem net no app, ele deixasse os dados das listas salvos para serem visualizados mesmo sem ter internet.

Comment: Bom, fiz essa pergunta mas depois fui verificar que o *Parse* tem sua própria metodologia de [local datastore](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/).

Comment: @Paulo Rodrigues. Sou sincero em dizer que nãos sei como criar um banco de dados, por isso recorri ao parse.com que por sinal é uma plataforma muito boa, porém por ser uma tecnologia "nova", não se tem muitos exemplos para auxiliar. Fico no aguardo por alguma resposta.

Comment: @Filipe Oliveira. Vocês poderiam tirar a suspensão?

Comment: @qmechanik. Vocês poderiam tirar a suspensão?

Comment: @RonySueliton a suspensão foi retirada.

Comment: @williamhk2. Muito Obrigado